# Why won't my gas fireplace start up?

Tags: gas, fireplace

Just recently purchased a house but have not as yet moved to the new locale. Gas fireplace has the functional gas shut-off key and a handheld remote with a fresh battery; however, no click, no flame. The two D-cells are missing beneath the fireplace pit amidst the mechanics. After replacing the batteries -- what might be next?

Comment: Would have gas guy/girl come and check it out.  Might be simple has no gas or a dirty sensor.  If you don't know gas, you can also be on youtube, as in unscheduled rapid house deconstruction.  You also don't know what the previous owners did to it.

Comment: Are you sure the gas is turned on? The previous owners probably had it turned off when they left.

Answer (score 3):

Have a closer look at the gas valve. Is there a manual control knob for setting off-pilot-on? If so then the remote control system may be an add-on that allows to light the fireplace, but only after you've manually lit the pilot and set the control valve to the on position.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Greg Hill that the first thing to try is to use the manual gas control & igniter knob, maybe located under the fireplace logs or under the burner.

Also, I know that propane gas can get "stale" sitting in a pipe all year long (which means it's hard to light), and it takes a while to draw fresh gas into the gas orifice, especially when you're trying to light the flame on the ignitor.  May take a minute or two for fresh gas to come out.  Be patient.

Mine has a knob.  You turn the knob to the pilot position. This allows gas to flow, but at a very low rate. Then if you push the knob in, you hear the igniter sparking (provided the batteries are good).  Like I said, it may take a while to purge the old gas from the line.

If you get the fireplace lit this way, then you can go on to troubleshoot the problem with the remote.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortably with DIY projects, you *could* confirm that the unit has both electric power and gas. You should *absolutely* determine the model number and  find a local professional that can maintain this in the future.

Will other gas appliances in the home function?  If so, check the shutoff valve to this appliance to ensure it is in the on position.  If you have any concerns about the integrity of the appliance and the shutoff valve is off, it is time to call a professional to check gas pressures and for the presence of gas leaks.  If other gas appliances work and the shutoff to this appliance is "on" to allow gas into the appliance, you are done confirming that gas "should" be available.

Now it is time to check the electrical power to the appliance. Look for the model number and download the user manual online.  You might find the model number by opening a grate to access below the unit or looking online for devices with a similar appearance/ manufacturer to get the manual.

Once you have the model number and the user manual, there will be a troubleshooting checklist there.  If that shows how to check the voltage and or replace batteries inside the unit, do that.

Ultimately, you should call a professional and tell them the model number.  This will help them show up with the right spare parts, or tell you they won't service that particular model. No point in having someone come to your door for a service fee (typically 150 to 250 dollars) just to say they can't help.